# Jena Query Execution time

Tags: jena

I wonder if for sparql query, there is some logging that can be activated that can provide the query execution time, or is this just something that must be done as part of the code that call the query ?

Answer (score 0):

Not as such.

It's also important to remember that Jena uses a streaming query engine so when you call `QueryExecution.execSelect()` it is not executing the full query rather preparing an iterator that can answer the query.  Only when you iterate the results does the query actually get executed so calling code must take this into account when looking to take timings.

Exact behaviour differs with the query kind:

- `SELECT`

  - `execSelect()` returns a `ResultSet` backed by an iterator that evaluates the query as it is iterated, exhaust the `ResultSet` by iteration to actually execute the query.  So time the full iterator exhaustion to time the query execution.
- `ASK`

  - `execAsk()` creates the iterator and calls `hasNext()` on it to get the boolean result, so only need to time `execAsk()`
- `CONSTRUCT`/`DESCRIBE`

  - `execConstruct()`/`execDescribe()` fully evaluates the query and returns the resulting model so can just time this call.
  - Alternatively `execConstructTriples()`/`execDescribeTriples()` just prepares an iterator, exhaust the iterator to actually execute the query.

You might want to take a look at a tool like [SPARQL Query Benchmarker](https://github.com/rvesse/sparql-query-bm) if you are just looking to benchmark specific queries on your data (or see examples of how to do this kind of timings).

**Disclaimer** - This was a tool developed and released as OSS as part of my $dayjob some years back.  It's using quite outdated versions of Jena but the core techniques still apply.